# Sample Case Numbers for Respective IDs

Tags: python, pandas, random

I have a pandas dataframe of IDs that looks something like this:

```
id = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[2,2]], columns = ['ID','# of places worked'])
```

| ID | # of places worked |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |

I also have a pandas dataframe of cases that looks something like this:

```
cases = pd.DataFrame(
[[1,123],[1,345],[1,456],[1,789],[1,132],[2,133],[2,143],[2,465],[2,765]], 
columns = ['ID','Case ID'])
```

| ID | Case ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 345 |
| 1 | 456 |
| 1 | 789 |
| 1 | 132 |
| 2 | 133 |
| 2 | 143 |
| 2 | 465 |
| 2 | 765 |

I want to randomly sample 3 case IDs for all the IDs in id. This would be the ideal output:

| ID | Case ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 456 |
| 1 | 789 |
| 1 | 132 |
| 2 | 143 |
| 2 | 465 |
| 2 | 765 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a x sized sample of a dataframe with df.sample(n = x); so, to get what you want, you can do this for each sub-dataframe where ID = ..., and concat the results:

```
pd.concat([cases[cases['ID'] == x].sample(n=3) for x in list(id['ID'])])
```